# android.applicationVariants.size() always returns 0

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I noticed that `application.applicationVariants.size()` always returns 0, although I know there are variants, since I can iterate them: `android.applicationVariants.all {println it}`. Because of that I am also not able to iterate the collection with `each`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior. Notice this sentence in the [changelog](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) (v 0.5.5):

> access to the variants container don't force creating the task. This
>   means android.[application|Library|Test]Variants will be empty during
>   the evaluation phase. To use it, use .all instead of .each